# Can you factor out vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My prof introduced eigenvalues to us today:

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. If there a scalar $\lambda$ and an $n-1$ non-zero column vector $u$, then
>
> $$Au = \lambda u$$
>
> then $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue and $u$ is called an eigenvector.
>
> $$Au - \lambda u = 0$$
> $$\implies (A - \lambda I)u = 0$$
> $$\implies \det(A - \lambda I) = 0$$

How did he get from $Au - \lambda u = 0$ to $\implies (A - \lambda I)u = 0$? It looks like he factored out the vector, but I thought you could only factor out constants? If you can factor out vectors can you explain why?

Comment: Try to do a number example. Take a 2by2 matrix A and a 2by1 vector. Subject the vector to A and then to $\lambda I$ and subtract. Then first subtract the matrices and then multiply by the vector. As you see how the numbers are"moving" you understand why you can do that

Comment: @adsf A better way to phrase it is that he's collecting operators in parentheses. That is to say, when you take the vectors $Au$ and $\lambda u$ and subtract the second from the first, this is the same as applying $A - \lambda I$ to $u$.

Comment: @ABlumenthal: Make it an answer?

Comment: @CameronBuie Doesn't look like I have to anymore : P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributive laws apply to matrix (or matrix-vector) multiplication.

$$\eqalign{(A+B) C &= AC + BC\cr
           A(C+D) &= AC + AD\cr}$$
whenever $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ have the right dimensions for these to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

"Factoring" in this case is just applying the distributive property in reverse, and since the distributive property holds for matrix multiplication, this is indeed possible.

The one quirk that still might be an impediment for you is that the scalar multiplication $\lambda u$ is identical with the matrix product $(\lambda I) u$. Once this is known, what you wrote is just an application of the distributive law.